# PhD Proposal: Application for funding

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, funding, research-proposal

I am applying for a PhD and currently rewriting the proposal which will submitted alongside my application.

I would appreciate guidance on whether it is wise to include the names of possible funding grants which you hope to apply for in the future. With some of the grants, it's not possible to apply until you have a confirmed place. However, there is one or two which you can apply either before your application or after you have secured a place.

Basically, should I include possible funding opportunities in the research methods section of a proposal? If you have applied before, did you include possible funding grants within your application?

I would greatly appreciate your feedback.

Comment: What country is this for? What field?